# Loop over computers in domain except computers that are off

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to loop over all the computers in my domain and display their name, description and last shutdown time. This is the beginning of a larger project to better track PC maintenance. The script I have so far works pretty well:

```powershell
$strFilter = "computer"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree" 
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000 
$objSearcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=$strFilter)"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($i in $colResults)
{
    try{
        $wmi = $i.getDirectoryEntry()
        $lastShutdownTime = get-wmiobject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $wmi.name
        $Description =  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $wmi.name |Select Description
        write-host $wmi.Name, $Description, $lastShutdownTime.convertToDateTime($lastShutdownTime.lastBootUpTime)
    }
    catch [system.exception]{

        "Could not reach $wmi.name"
    }
}
```

Except that when I hit a computer that is OFF, I get an error that ignores my try/catch block. How can I write this so that it ignores computers that are currently off or, at least, doesn't error on them?

Other info: I won't be able to use the AD module for this, sadly.

Comment: It would probably help if you try a test-connection first to see if they're up before you throw a get-wmiobject at them.

Answer (score 0):

Add *-ErrorAction Stop* to `get-wmiobject` commands. Change:

```powershell
$lastShutdownTime = get-wmiobject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $wmi.name
$Description =  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $wmi.name |Select Description
```

to

```powershell
$lastShutdownTime = get-wmiobject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $wmi.name -ErrorAction Stop
$Description =  Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $wmi.name -ErrorAction Stop |Select Description
```